# Magnetic force on open circuit?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

Let's say we have a straight horizontal wire and we let it drop inside a magnetic field which will be parallel to the ground(coming out of the screen). Charges inside the wire feel a force due to their movement inside the magnetic field .

Let's say the field is coming out of the screen. Positive charges gather on the left and negative on the right. If we had a loop I would have no trouble with this but during the charges' movement do we consider that we have a current? Therefore leading to a magnetic force opposing the bar's drop or not?

Answer (score 0):

> So I'll have to ask again, does this ever stop? Is equilibrium ever
>   reached?

Prompted by the comments to reexamine the question, I now better understand the question.

Essentially, this is the canonical rod moving in a perpendicular magnetic field extended to the case that there is a constant external applied force.

Clearly, unless there is an oppositely directed magnetic force that cancels the applied force, the rod will accelerate.

But an accelerated rod implies an increasing magnetic force (on charge) parallel to the rod.

Further, if the mobile charge is moving parallel to the rod (an electric current), there is a magnetic force against the external applied force.

What then is *equilibrium* (the stationary case)?

As user Farcher points out in the comments, the work done by the external can go into the potential energy of the separated charge but it can also go into the kinetic energy of the rod.

(to be continued... it's late now)

---

You're correct that there is a current but it is a *transient* current.

As the mobile charge redistributes due to the magnetic force, another force develops - the electric force due to the field from the redistributed charge.

Charge moves just until the electric force and magnetic force on mobile charge cancel out.

Comment: That clarifies some things. However, will the bar feel a force opposing its drop or not? In other words , does the transient current produce magnetic force F=BIL?

Comment: @JohnKatsantas The redistribution of electric charges represents an increase in electric potential energy. This energy comes from the decrease in gravitational energy ie the wire does not gain as much kinetic energy as you might expect until the movement of charges (current) stops. So there is a force in opposition to the motion of the wire as long as the charges are redistributing themselves ie as long as there is a current in the wire.

Comment: That's a great way to say it. The voltage induced is V=BvL if I'm correct. Since the bar keeps dropping its speed increases and so does the induced voltage. So let's say we've reached a point of equilibrium in which what you said is the case. The bar accelerates and since induced voltage is bigger redistribution must continue in order to cancel the new stronger magnetic force. So I'll have to ask again, does this ever stop? Is equilibrium ever reached?

Comment: @JohnKatsantas, I understand better what you're asking and I answered too quick without giving enough thought to your question.  I have to step out for awhile and then cook some supper.  If someone else hasn't correctly answered in that time, I'll add to my answer to address your comment above.